# jsonp callBack function not called

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, web-services, jsonp

Ive looked around at a number of other posts on this topic but Ive been unable to pinpoint my problem. Perhaps someone else can.

I've created a web service (http://utimktoservice.uti.edu/MarketoService.svc/getMktoDetails/email/test@uti.edu) to call another api and get data back. I am calling my web service (utimktoservice) using the folowing jQuery...

```
var mktoApiUrl = 'http://utimktoservice.uti.edu/MarketoService.svc/getMktoDetails/email/' + token;
$.ajax({
    url: mktoApiUrl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'GetMktoInfoResult',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('sucess - ' + result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("xhr (" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        console.log("status (" + status + ")");
        console.log("error (" + error + ")");
    }
});
```

my websrervice .cs file looks like

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMarketoService
{
    // FilterTypes: email, cookie
    [OperationContract]

    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/getMktoDetails/{filterType}/{filterVal}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
        //,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
        )]

    String GetMktoInfo(string filterType, string filterVal);
}
```

And my webservice .svc file looks like

```
public String GetMktoInfo(string filterType, string filterVal)
    {
        String token = GetAccessToken();
        String url = host + "/rest/v1/leads.json?access_token=" + token + "&filterType=" + filterType + "&filterValues=" + filterVal;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resStream);
        String data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("GetMktoInfoResult(");
        sb.Append(data);
        sb.Append(")");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

If I call my webservice directly in my browser I receive the following response:

> "GetMktoInfoResult({\"requestId\":\"b003#1594c9a833e\",\"result\":[{\"id\":20628195,\"updatedAt\":\"2016-12-09T18:19:37Z\",\"lastName\":\"Test\",\"email\":\"test@uti.edu\",\"createdAt\":\"2016-05-11T03:41:23Z\",\"firstName\":\"User\"}],\"success\":true})"

Its my understanding that because my webservice needs to return the result in jsonp format, the result simply needs to be wrapped in a function ("GetMktoInfoResult") and since my service is returning the result werapped in GetMktoInfoResult(), I need to specify that in my ajax call using the jsonpCallback parameter.

The log results Im receiving are:

> xhr (undefined)
>   status (parsererror)
>   error (Error: GetMktoInfoResult was not called)

So what is the parse error due to? Bad formatting (the backslashes?) in the jsonp results? And why the GetMktoInfoResult not called error?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: The backslashes shouldn't be there when you go to the url in your browser

Comment: I think the problem is that your `.cs` file says the response is JSON. So it's converting the string that you return to JSON format, which wraps the whole thing in quotes and escapes all the inner quotes.

Comment: You need to change it so it just sends the response without any reformatting.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the input. Not sure how to change the response to have no formatting. WebMessageFormat only has two option - Json and Xml. If I comment out ResponseFormat entirely, the format defaults to xml...

Comment: If I remove all of the double quotes then the backslashes are removed from the webservice's output as well. But Im still receiving the same "parserror" and [callback function] "was not called" errors.

Comment: [how to support JSONP in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511(v=vs.110).aspx)